# Arduino Pyserial Communication is too slow

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication

```c
#include <Servo.h>

String incomingByte ;
Servo frri, frle, reri, rele, frriup, frleup, reriup, releup; // the motors we used, there are 8 motor fr = front, ri = right, le = left, le = left
int frri_speed, frle_speed, reri_speed, rele_speed, frriup_speed, frleup_speed, reriup_speed, releup_speed = 1500; // the motors speed it's between 1000 and 2000 when we send 1500 to motors, they stop

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  frri.attach(3, 1000, 2000);// 
  frle.attach(8, 1000, 2000);// 
  reri.attach(5, 1000, 2000);// 
  rele.attach(6, 1000, 2000);// 
  frriup.attach(9, 1000, 2000);// 
  frleup.attach(2, 1000, 2000);// 
  reriup.attach(7, 1000, 2000);// 
  releup.attach(4, 1000, 2000);// 
  frri.writeMicroseconds(1500); // Motors we used is controlled by servo library
  frle.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  reri.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  rele.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  frriup.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  frleup.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  reriup.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  releup.writeMicroseconds(1500);
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) { // checks if there is a message
    incomingByte = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); // its reads the message for example = "15001500194019401500150015001500"
    if (incomingByte.length() == 32) {
      frri_speed = (incomingByte.substring(0, 4)).toInt();
      frle_speed = (incomingByte.substring(4, 8)).toInt();
      reri_speed = (incomingByte.substring(8, 12)).toInt();
      rele_speed = (incomingByte.substring(12, 16)).toInt();
      frriup_speed = (incomingByte.substring(16, 20)).toInt();
      frleup_speed = (incomingByte.substring(20, 24)).toInt();
      reriup_speed = (incomingByte.substring(24, 28)).toInt();
      releup_speed = (incomingByte.substring(28, 32)).toInt();
      frri.writeMicroseconds(frri_speed);
      frle.writeMicroseconds(frle_speed);
      reri.writeMicroseconds(reri_speed);
      rele.writeMicroseconds(rele_speed);
      frriup.writeMicroseconds(frriup_speed);
      frleup.writeMicroseconds(frleup_speed);
      reriup.writeMicroseconds(reriup_speed);
      releup.writeMicroseconds(releup_speed);
      delay(5);
    }
  }
}
```

First of all sorry for my bad English, I use pyserial communicate Arduino and Jetson Nano. I send my data which is 32 char of integer like 150015001500150015001500150015001500 to Ardunio. It works until there but Arduino cannot read data fast and correctly.

Comment: how often do you send data to arduino?

Answer (score 0):

## First of all

Make sure that you don't send any data **that are never received** from `arduino` or from `python script`

## Arduino <--> Python communication guide

### arduino

I suggest you to use the `serialEvent()` this function will be called when you are receiving some data

```
bool stringComplete = false;
String inputString = "";

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // you can remove this if block if you want your string to contain '\n'
    if (inChar == '\n')
    {
      stringComplete = true;
      break;
    }
    inputString += inChar;
  }
}
```

Then in your `loop()` you will have something like that

```
  if (stringComplete)
  {
    //here you have your inputString ready to use
    
    //remember to reset your variable
    stringComplete = false;
    inputString = "";
  }
```

### python script

You will have something like this

```
import serial
# set up connection 
# you have to put your address '/dev/ttyACM0' is an example
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, writeTimeout=0)
#send data
ser.write(your_string_data.encode())
```